# Change push and commit date time in Github activity View and upload old projects with old date

Tags: git, github

I have problems, which is that I have old projects such as the graduation project, but unfortunately I did not upload these projects on GitHub, but at this time I decided to put the previous projects on GitHub.

so I searched for a way to change the date of the commit and I found this command solution to change date -

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Apr 21 11:34 2023 +0530" git commit -m "add" --amend --date="Apr 21 11:34 2023 +0530"
```

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyut4.png)

But when I do this, the date changes successfully, but the problem is that the real date appears in the activity view when I push commits like

```
git push -f origin main
```

It shows the real time of push in activity view as like picture.

Therefore, there is a difference between the two dates, and this method fails. I want a solution so that the date in the date matches the date of the commit?

The second question, if there is no solution, what is the best solution to put these projects on GitHub and put them in the C.V
Can I not mention the real date of the projects in the C.V , but it will conflict with the date of uploading them to GitHub if you upload them at the present time?

I tried this solution but it fails -

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Apr 21 11:34 2023 +0530" git commit -m
"add"

--amend --date="Apr 21 11:34 2023 +0530"
```

and real time appears in activity view as I had explained before